# Upload a file to Amazon S3 via Android Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3, android-service

I have created a sample application in order to test uploading a sample file to `Amazon S3` via Android Studio using the `AWS Mobile SDK` as described in the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html) from Amazon for interacting with AWS within Android Studio, but I am having issues with the file not being uploaded.

For the purposes of this test I have captured an image from the Camera which is located in the `images` folder of the devices file browser, under the filename of `Test.jpg`. I can also access this file via `Device storage/DCIM/Camera/Test.jpg`.

I've also followed the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html) from Amazon in order to develop the code in charge of uploading to S3. At this point I am simply trying to achieve this functionality with Unauth and S3FullAccess just for the initial tests.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

**import(s)**

*The imports I have in my MainActivity.java that are related to Amazon S3 usage are here.*

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferListener;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferState;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
```

**Build.gradle** (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.devonryder.s3_testing"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Dependencies for AWS and S3
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Get the File of the Test.jpg located in DCIM/Camera directory
    File fileToUpload = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "Camera/Test.jpg");

    AmazonS3 s3;
    TransferUtility transferUtility;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the button from the layout and set the onClickListener, passing the current context
        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadFile);
        upload.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Callback method to call credentialsProvider method.
        credentialsProvider();

        // Callback method to call the setTransferUtility method
        setTransferUtility();
    }

    // Implement the OnClickListener callbacks
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnUploadFile) {
            // For easy Debug
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked btn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Set the File to be uploaded to S3
            setFileToUpload();
        }
    }

    public void credentialsProvider(){

        // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "us-east-1:??????????????????????", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
        );

        // Pass the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider instantiate the S3Client
        setAmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    }

    /**
     *  Create a AmazonS3Client and pass the credentialsProvider.
     * @param credentialsProvider
     */
    public void setAmazonS3Client(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider){

        // Create an S3 client
        s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

        // Set the region of your S3 bucket
        s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

    }

    public void setTransferUtility() {

        transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to upload the file to S3 by using TransferUtility class
     */
    public void setFileToUpload(){

        TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
                "validBuckitName", // The bucket to upload to
                "test_photo",  // The key for the uploaded object
                fileToUpload   // The file where the data to upload exists
        );

        transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
    }

    /**
     * This is listener method of the TransferObserver
     * An error will be displayed if there is problem uploading the file to S3.
     * @param transferObserver
     */

    public void transferObserverListener(TransferObserver transferObserver){

        transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener(){

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                Log.e("statechange: ", state + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent/bytesTotal * 100);
                Log.e("percentage: ", percentage + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Log.e("error: ", ex.getMessage());
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I run the application and click the button, but I am not receiving any status in the console, or any errors that indicate why my file is not uploading to S3.

**Update**

I've found that I had an invalid filename when I was attempting to load the file from storage. The line has been changed to include the proper `/` after the `DCIM` path.

```
File fileToUpload = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "/Camera/Test.jpg");
```

However, this does not fix the root issue.

I've enabled logging for the bucket now and after I try to upload there is an auto-generated file that is created in the bucket. In short, it seems to notify me that access to the bucket has been denied. This file seems to be XML.

The following is a portion of the main  root node:

```
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

Comment: Did you check Cognito logs? If any clues there?

Comment: @Nambari I have not, as I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: This might help: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-using-import-tool-cli-cloudwatch-iam-role.html and are you really sure LogCat not showing any messages?

Comment: @Nambari So, I should create the role and policy and then attempt the upload again? After the test, view the logs somewhere in the console?

Comment: yes, that is correct, this is just to see the logs, is not a fix for root cause.

Comment: @Nambari How do I view the logs after I've enabled them?

Comment: @Nambari Once i get to the policy portion I'm notified that the policy is not valid. I don't know if it will help in this situation, but I've enabled logging on the bucket in question and updated the OP with some further information.